# Número triangular

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber, por que quando digito no programa abaixo que verifica se o número digitado é triangular, ou seja, é múltiplo de três números consecutivos, como exemplo o 60 ele imprime dois "NAO" e um "SIM", e quando digito 336 aparecem cinco "NAO" e um "SIM"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numero, i;
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    for(i = 1 ; i*(i+1)*(i+2)<=numero ; i++)    
    {
        if(i*(i+1)*(i+2)==numero)
        {
            printf("SIM\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NAO");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando `i` for `1` o programa vai fazer o if

```
if (1 * 2 * 3 == numero)
```

e ou imprime "SIM\n" ou imprime "NAO".
Quando o `i` for `2` o if passa a ser

```
if (2 * 3 * 4 == numero)
```

e o programa imprime "SIM\n" ou "NAO".

Ou seja, o programa imprime qualquer coisa sempre que corre o loop. O que tu queres e imprimir apenas uma vez, no fim do loop.

O uso duma variable auxiliar pode-te ajudar:

```
int variavel_auxiliar = 0;
for(i = 1 ; i*(i+1)*(i+2)<=numero ; i++)    
{
    if(i*(i+1)*(i+2)==numero)
    {
        variavel_auxiliar = 1;
    }
}
if (variavel_auxiliar) printf("SIM\n");
else                   printf("NAO\n");
```

Comment: (+1) ou mesmo `for(i = 1 ; i*(i+1)*(i+2)<numero ; i++){}
if(i*(i+1)*(i+2)==numero) { printf("SIM\n"); }else { printf("NAO"); }`

Comment: (o if está fora do ciclo)

Comment: os *braces* vazios enganaram-me :)

Comment: E a desformatação dos comentários tb nao ajuda nada :)

Comment: por causa disso eu costumo por `/* void */` nos sítios vazios: `for (a, b, c) { /* void */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Para saber quais são os números triangulares até determinada posição eu fiz um código:

```
int main(){
    int limitador=0,i;

    printf("Digite ate qual posicao voce quer saber o numero triangular: ");
    scanf("%d",&limitador);
        while(limitador < 0 || limitador > 1290){
        printf("Valor invalido!! Digite um numero entre 0 e 1290: ");
        scanf("%d",&limitador); 
        }
    for(i=0; i<limitador; i++)
        printf("%d x %d x %d =%d\n",i,i+1,i+2,i*(i+1)*(i+2));

    system("pause");    
    return 0;
}
```

Observação: O código só vai até a posição 1290 porque na próxima posição o resultado passa da quantidade de um valor inteiro na linguagem C.

Answer (score 0):

O código em questão não chega a validar se um número é triangular ou não, pois veja, se multiplicarmos 2, 3 e 4 (ou seja, três números consecutivos) o resultado será 24, sendo este um número não triangular(o 6º termo triangular é 21 e o 7º é 28), da mesma forma se quisermos validar 10 como sendo um número triangular não seria possível, pois não existe sequência de três números multiplicados que resultem neste valor.
Todo número é triangular quando resultado da soma de N números consecutivos; exemplo: 1 + 2 = 3 (triangular), para encontrar os próximos termos somasse 3, depois 4, depois 5 e assim sucessivamente.
Um número triangular é dado também pela fórmula: Tn=n*(n +1)/2; utilizaremos ela para fazer o calculo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int numero, i, auxiliar = 0;
    scanf("%d",&numero); //escaneamos o resultado triangular

//aqui percorremos o index "i" ate alcançar o dobro do numero que esta sendo analisado
//pois assim garantimos que eles nunca serao impares durante a analise
    for(i = 1 ; (i*(i+1))<=(numero*2) ; i++){ 
        if((i*(i+1)/2)==numero){ //validamos se o resultado é de fato triangular
            auxiliar = 1; //caso sim, utilizamos a variavel auxiliar como um boolean
        }
    }
    if(auxiliar)
        printf("SIM, EH TRIANGULAR\n");
    else
        printf("NAO EH TRIANGULAR\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O autor da pergunta quer saber o motivo porque o algoritmo dele está emitindo varia vezes as mensagem de confirmação e negação.  Existem maneiras diretas de verificar se um número é triangular sem recorrer a laços de iteração, por exemplo https://ideone.com/r58oyR